# When I change my context in an element it is not updated in other elemnts that use the same context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am making a user context that has all of my user information that I need initially it is null and I update it in the login page but after I login and try to access the context from any other page it is still null

here is the code

**CurrentUserContext.js**

```
import { createContext } from "react";
export const CurrentUserContext = createContext(null);
```

**UserContextLayout.jsx**

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useMemo, useCallback } from "react";
import { CurrentUserContext } from "../hooks/CurrentUserContext";

const UserContextLayout = () => {
  const [currentUserContext, setCurrentUserContext] = useState(null);

  return (
    <CurrentUserContext.Provider
      value={[currentUserContext, setCurrentUserContext]}
    >
      <Outlet />
    </CurrentUserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default UserContextLayout;
```

**MainRouter.jsx**

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Signin from "./pages/Signin";
import LandingPage from "./pages/LandingPage";
import { isAuthenticated } from "./apis/auth/auth-helper";
import UserContextLayout from "./utils/UserContextLayout";

const MainRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<UserContextLayout />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />}></Route>
        <Route
          path="/signin"
          element={
            !isAuthenticated() ? <Signin /> : <Navigate to="/" replace={true} />
          }
        ></Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default MainRouter;
```

**Signin.jsx**

```
import { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { GrTechnology } from "react-icons/gr";
import { CurrentUserContext } from "../hooks/CurrentUserContext";
import { signin } from "../apis/auth/auth-api";
import { authenticate } from "../apis/auth/auth-helper";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Signin = () => {
  const [currentUserContext, setCurrentUserContext] =
    useContext(CurrentUserContext);

  const navigate = useNavigate();


  const [user1, setUser1] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const [rememberMe, setrememberMe] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setUser1((prev) => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
  };

  const handleRememberMeClick = () => {
    setrememberMe((prev) => !prev);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await signin(user1);

      // if (res.status == 200) {
      setCurrentUserContext(response.data.user);

      authenticate(response.data.token, rememberMe);
      navigate("/");

      // } else {
      //   throw new Error("Authentication failed");
      // }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div >
        <div >
          

            <h2 >
              Sign in to your account
            </h2>
       
          <div >
  
            <div>
              <div>
                <label htmlFor="email-address">
                  Email address
                </label>
                <input
                  id="email-address"
                  name="email"
                  type="email"
                  autoComplete="email"
                  required
                  
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label htmlFor="password">
                  Password
                </label>
                <input
                  id="password"
                  name="password"
                  type="password"
                  autoComplete="current-password"
                  required
                  
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div >
              <div >
                <input
                  id="remember-me"
                  name="remember-me"
                  type="checkbox"
                  
                  onClick={handleRememberMeClick}
                />
                <label
                  htmlFor="remember-me"
                 
                >
                  Remember me
                </label>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div>
              <button
                type="submit"
                
                onClick={handleSubmit}
              >
                Sign in
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Signin;
```

response.data.user has the user data that I want to save in the context but the context is not updated when I call setCurrentUserContext

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with the code snippet, and I don't see any reason for an enqueued React state update wouldn't be processed. How exactly are you verifying/validating this state update?

Comment: Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/when-i-change-my-context-in-an-element-it-is-not-updated-in-other-elemnts-that-u-i5l3h7) of your code and I can't reproduce any state updating issue as you describe.

Comment: I just noticed that the code works but whenever I refresh the page the context is gone but I want the context to be available as long as the user is logged in does that mean that I need to save the data in either local or session storage?

Comment: Yes, React state is in-memory, you'll need to persist the React state somewhere longterm like localStorage so it survives a page reload. Do you need help with this aspect or do you have a good idea what to do from here?

Comment: I think I know how to do it